# How do you change the title bar color in a Windows Universal app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I am looking to change the colors of the title bar to better suit my app similar to what has been done in the Mail app.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The background and foreground colors of parts of the TitleBar can be changed as follows.

```
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
```

Be aware that these changes happen after the app has displayed so the user will see the colors change.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be changing the color of the status bar on Windows 10 mobile.  Do I have to do something different for that?

Comment: Not sure if still needed, but when you want to change the color of the statusbar, you'll need to add extra code. First see if you are on a Mobile family : `if(Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Mobile")` After that, grab the statusbar and set the ForegroundColor and BackgroundColo

Comment: @Depechie Do not inspect the DeviceFamily; that is analytics information, not for programmatic decisions. To see if the status bar API is available (note: Status bar may be present on devices other than Mobile), use `Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar")`.

Comment: @RaymondChen true... wasn't aware of that API info key until recently :)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the background of the title bar by doing the following:

```
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
var titleBar = appView.TitleBar;
titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
```

You can change the other colors of the title bar like the foreground color or the button colors by changing the color in the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the buttons and title text by adding a extend view into the title bar. please find the code snippet for this.

```
private void ExtendViewOftitleBar()
{
        CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
        ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = view.TitleBar;
        view.SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
        titleBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
        titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

}